# using a theme .zip file for my home screen

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, home-screen, nexus-5

I was looking for customize my homescreen and found  [this](http://mycolorscreen.com/2013/08/02/style-8/) screen attractive.
I have already downloaded the zip file given there, but don't know how to use them.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the software the page links to in the top right: Nova Launcher and Ultimate Custom Widget. The files in the zip include a wallpaper (which you set through the launcher's settings), a theme for Nova Launcher, and settings to use with the widget. Once you've installed the right software and played with its settings, it should become obvious how you need to use the files.

Comment: Nova lanucher is a marvelous homescreen replacement, and I recommend it myself. UCCW Widget needs to be installed from the Play Store and also the theme/zip you have there. Place a widget on a homescreen, select UCCW and the size you want e.g. 4x4 or 4x2, then in UCCW itself select the widget you want... that is the zip you have downloaded. UCCW does nothing by itself it uses the extensions/themes/zips that people create for it. The play store has LOADS. Also in Nova/Apex/Quick launcher you can download icon sets too to further skin your device.